# What is the name of this type of vector product?

Tags: reference-request, vectors

I'd like to multiply two vectors

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
    x \\
    y
  \end{bmatrix}*\begin{bmatrix}
    u \\
    v
  \end{bmatrix} $$
so that the product is
$$=\begin{bmatrix}
    xu \\
    yv
  \end{bmatrix}.$$

There's dot products and cross products of vectors, is there a name for this type of product?

Comment: Hadamard product.

Comment: Also known as a componentwise product. It has some uses, but they're fairly few and far between.

Comment: For some more details see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)).

Comment: @Doug Thanks, I think that's what I was looking for.

Comment: Wikipedia's article specifies matrices, you're positive this applies to 1 x n vectors?